# How change DOM elements which are add from a secondary document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery doesn't work to hide text inside a div that was added from an external document.

I am sending both files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - here is a guide how to ask questions

Comment: it will hide but for that you will have to wait for jquery to execute first part first. So just add some timeout function for the hide code and it will work.

Comment: your question is incomplete, but I think you're inserting new elements from another page. in that case you must run your code after page finishes loading. you can try rewriting your code like this: `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#newElement").hide(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#newElement").hide(); /// Id/Class of the element which you want to hide
    }, 2000); /// add some time. here 2000 means 2 second
});
```

Learn about timeout from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: It did not work regularly. It worked the first time and after several attempts. By including in
$ ("# btn"). click (function () {...}), there was no action.